# IF statement with Condtional Formating Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to do an IF statement that has 2 outcomes:

1. I want it to say a word
2. I want it to be a color

For example:

```
IF {Command.Check in/Appt} < 0  
   THEN "Early" AND crGreen
ELSE "LATE" AND crRed
```

In the above example the `AND` does not work.

> A Boolean is required here.

So I just need to find a way to have those 2 outcomes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of using shared variables, you can't do that. One formula, one output.

But there's nothing saying you can't have two nearly identical formulas, (One for `Early`/`Late`, one for `Red`/`Green`) - And in Crystal, that's the best way to do it. (Glad to see you figured that out on your own.)

---

The reason the `AND` keyword was giving you trouble is because [`AND` is a Boolean operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction). Whenever you use `AND`, you're basically using this function:

> Take booleans `FOO` and `BAR` as input.
>
> I return `true` if, and only if, `FOO` and `BAR` are *both* true.
> If at least one of them is false, I return `false`.

So the `AND` keyword was expecting two booleans for input. Instead you gave it a string and a color. Ask a machine if the color Red is equal to true, it's going to complain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, while I didn't find a solution by adding it in the formula, I did find a solution.

For those who have the same problem, just keep the `IF` statement:

```
IF {Command.Check in/Appt} < 0  
THEN "Early"
ELSE "LATE"
```

Then save and go to `Format` > `Highlight Expert` to enter the formatting conditions you like.

In the above case, I did:

- `New` > `Value of:` `this field` `is equal to` "Early" `Font color` Green
- `New` > `Value of:` `this field` `is equal to` "Late" `Font color` Red